# How to Decide what Google MySQL Machine to Use

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, cloud

For those of you who have created cloud MySQL products before on Google or AWS, or for those of you who are admins of such systems, how do you decide what machines/instance types to use?

For example - if you were developing a product that would require say fifty databases on an instance, where each one's largest table size was around 1GB, and each DB would be queried maybe 10 times a minute, how would you decide what spec instance you need? What if you needed to host 100 DBs? 1000 DBs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "small" MySQL setup.  Start with the smallest config available; upgrade if needed.  Rethink the schema if you expect to have thousands of Databases or thousands of Tables in a single Database.